# Check if div has a background image set

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check if a specific div has a background image URL set.

Here's the structure without a background image:

```
<div id="page-header">
  <div class="bg">
    <div class="bg-layer-upper-image" style=" background-image: url();">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the structure with one set (they're dynamic):

```
<div id="page-header">
  <div class="bg">
    <div class="bg-layer-upper-image" style=" background-image: url('https://example.com/images/background-1.jpeg');">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's my JQuery - it always thinks there's a background image though:

```
if ( $('#page-header').find('.bg-layer-upper-image').css('background-image') != 'url()' ) {
  alert('There is a background image');
}
```

Any idea why that is?

Comment: When I check in Chrome, the browser interprets `url()` as `url("")`. It's probably different for other browsers too. You might need to use a regex test

Comment: Even more fun, when computed that empty URL is actually treated as a relative path where `""` becomes the current page URL. With that in mind, `url()` is actually setting a background-image to an invalid image URL. Does it have to be that way? Can you change it to `background-image: none`?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it outputs `background-image: url();` when it's blank. I can't really change that- it's part of the theme.

Comment: @Phil I ended up using `search()` to check if the URL contained my upload directory, see my answer below if you're curious.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, when you use Jquery to check background image url and if it is "url()", it's being evaluated as window.location. For example in jsfiddle it evaluates to "url("https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/")"

So try checking without jquery

```
if ($('#page-header').find('.bg-layer-upper-image')[0].style.backgroundImage 
   != 'url("")') {
  alert('There is a background image');
}
```

Comment: I checked with Chrome and Firefox and both interpret it as `url("")`. Not sure about IE / Edge or others though

Comment: @Phil: I am on chrome Version 75.0.3770.80 (Official Build) (64-bit).  https://jsfiddle.net/avdf4tn8/

Comment: Not sure what that's got to do with my comment. All I'm saying is that while your solution might work on Chrome and Firefox, you should check IE and Edge

Comment: @Phil: oh got it. sorry, I misunderstood ur comment.

Answer (score 1):

Solution in my case ended up being using `search()` to check if the background image URL contained the upload directory- since if it was blank the URL would just be the page URL

```
$background_image_url = $('#page-header').find('.bg-layer-upper-image').css('background-image');

if ( $background_image_url.search( 'wp-content' ) != -1 ) {

    // Do stuff

}
```

Comment: [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) would be a better fit